# @Value annotation always returning null

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, annotations

I'm trying to read the content in my application.properties file using the @Value annotation. But it will always return null back.

```html
**Sample Java code**

    @Component    
    public class SampleClass() implements Runnable{
        @Value("${profile.name}")
        private String name;
    
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            ...
        }
    }

**Application.properties**

    profile.name=myname

**Pom.xml**

    <profiles>
     <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
       <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
      </properties>
     </profile>
     <profile>
      <id>stag</id>
      <properties>
       <activatedProperties>stag</activatedProperties>
      </properties>
     </profile>
     <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
       <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
      </properties>
     </profile>
    </profiles>
    ....
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <includes>
           <include>**/*.properties</include>
          </includes>
         </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

I've even tried giving a default value to the variable and it still returning null.

```
@Value("${profile.name:'samplename'}")
```

Why??

**Update**

I managed to retrieve the profile.name value in my SampleClass() now. But i'm not really sure if the way I did was the correct way. SampleClass1 will call SampleClass2.

**Sample Java 1 Code**

```
@Component    
public class SampleClass1(){
    @Autowired
    SampleClass2 sampleClass2;

    @Value("${profile.name}")
    private String profileName;

    sampleClass2.setName(profileName);
    //Invoke SampleClass2
}
```

**Sample Java 2 Code**

```
@Component    
public class SampleClass2() implements Runnable{
    private String profileName;

    public void setName(String profileName){
        this.profileName= profileName;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + profileName);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the client code that uses the `run()` method? It looks like the instance of the SampleClass is not created by Spring.

Comment: Simply put it cannot be `null`, you either have a default value or your application blows up when starting. So you are probably using `new SampleClass()` instead of using the spring configured instance. Also the fact that you are using maven profiles and resource filtering with spring boot worries me a little (in short you don't need it nor should want it, use the Spring Boot support with profiles).

Comment: @M.Deinum @StanislavL. Yes, the class was called using `new SampleClass()`. what should be the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: You should inject it instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: Where's your `Application.properties` file located in your project?

Comment: @M.Deinum I've removed all the maven profiles and resource filtering from my pom.xml. You are right, they should not be there. Btw, i've updated my post. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Just use `@Value` where you need the property. You don't want to change around auto wired dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear.

```
@Component
@Getter
public class SampleComponentClass {

  @Value("${profile.name}")
  private String profileName;

}

@Component
Class SomeOtherClass{
    @Autowired
     SampleComponentClass sampleComponentClass;

    public void someMethod(){
     System.out.println(sampleComponentClass.getProfileName()); // prints testprofile
     SampleComponentClass sampleComponentClass1 = new SampleComponentClass();
     System.out.println(sampleComponentClass1.getProfileName()); // prints null
    }
}
```

In application.properties

```
profile.name=testprofile
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SampleClass must be a Bean. Add annotation to your class e.g. `@Component` to let Spring find it during scan and assign the value.

Comment: he needs to have component scan also enabled.

Comment: @StanislavL Oops sorry my bad. I accidentally missed out the `@Component` annotation in the original post. I've updated it already

Comment: @AmitK I just added the component scan annotation to my application.java file,but its still the same. I even printed out all the beans, my SampleClass was listed too.

Comment: Then show us how the SampleClass  is created. Looks like you manually create it e.g. by calling new SampleClass(). In this case Spring has no chance to init the property. It must be a bean.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting value in a config class and using instance of this component with autowired annotation could be a better approach.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
    @Value("${profile.name}")
    private String profileName;

    @Bean
    public SampleClass1 sampleClass1(){
        SampleClass1 sampleClass1 = new Sampleclass1();
        // This approach, you can make additional control and configuration here 
        sampleClass1.setProfileName(profileName);
        return sampleClass1;
    }
    @Bean
    public SampleClass2 sampleClass2(){
        return new SampleClass2();
    }
}
```

And wherever you need SampleClass1

```
public class SomeClass{
    @Autowired
    private SampleClass1 sampleClass1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SampleClass2 need to remove the () after the class name.

```
@Component
public class SampleClass2 implements Runnable {
    private String profileName;

    public void setName(String profileName) {
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + profileName);
    }
}
```

Then SampleClass1 should be either of below. Spring injects the value after the object is constructed.

[1]

```
@Component
public class SampleClass1 {
    @Autowired
    SampleClass2 sampleClass2;

    @Value("${profile.name}")
    private String profileName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sampleClass2.setName(profileName);
        //Invoke SampleClass2
    }
}
```

[2]

```
@Component
public class SampleClass1 {
    @Autowired
    public SampleClass1(SampleClass2 sampleClass2, @Value("${profile.name}") String profileName) {
        sampleClass2.setName(profileName);
        //Invoke SampleClass2
    }
}
```